# What's the best way to add or subtract 2 interpolated curves?

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

What's the best method to add or subtract 2 interpolated curves in Python. An example would be adding a credit spread to treasury rate. The 2 curves do not have the same term points. I can rebuild the curve by getting specific tenor but I was hoping there's a better way.

```
import scipy as sc
ATenor = [0.25,0.5,1,5,10,20]
ARate = [0.02,0.022,0.025,0.03,0.035,0.039]
ACurve = sc.interpolate.interp1d(ATenor,ARate)
BTenor = [0.25,1,4,5,7,10,15,20]
BRate = [0.025,0.28,0.032,0.036,0.038,0.042,0.04,0.038]
BCurve = sc.interpolate.interp1d(BTenor,BRate)
CCurve = ACurve + BCurve  # <-- This does not work but to get the idea across
```

If it try to add 2 interpolated curves I get this error:

unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'interp1d' and 'interp1d'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a new `interp1d` object, then you can merge the tenor arrays (x-axis) and recalculate the rate values (y-axis). For example, this code will do:

```
ABTenor = sorted(set(ATenor + BTenor))              # Merge points on the x-axis.
ABCurve = [ACurve(x) + BCurve(x) for x in ABTenor]  # Compute y values.
ABCurve = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(ABTenor, ABCurve)
```

Alternatively, you can create a lazy evaluation function:

```
def add_curves(A, B):
    def compute(x):
        return A(x) + B(x)
    return compute

ABCurve = add_curves(ACurve, BCurve)
# ABCurve(10.0) will call ACurve(10.0) and BCurve(10.0) and sum the results.
```

Comment: Cool! That def compute(x) inside I've never seen before. What is this method called so I can do some more research, like how 'x' got defined? I may have to go with the first method since it's faster and I need to run this over a million times in a nested stochastic projection.

Comment: Search for _closures_. Here, `compute` is simply a function of one variable `x`, that's how it got defined. However, it can access local variables `A` and `B` of the parent function, even though that function already finished its execution. Check also *lambda functions*.